# Zookeeper：how many nodes can zookeeper support?

Tags: config, apache-zookeeper

**Background**:
In our team,we use zookeeper to process when configure changed.

**Question**:
1、Zookeeper can support how much `nodes`.

2、What factors can affect zookeeper supported nodes，cpu、disk or network?

Answer (score 0):

1. Zookeeper can support as many nodes as you wish. It is distributed coordination service that doesn't get affected by the number of nodes you vary in the network. It only matters if the application involves more reads/writes. Zookeeper is most suited when there are more reads, although it works well with writes too.
2. Zookeeper doesn't get affected by the CPU or the Disk. Since the underlying consensus Protocol in Zookeeper is ZAB, which takes care of CP in CAP theorem. Partitioning of the network is tolerated along with maintaining the consistency using atomic broadcast protocol.